# AnyChart, AnyGantt Live Edit: Is disabling handles of single tasks possible?

Tags: javascript, anychart

We use AnyChart to visualize and edit project plans with a Gantt Diagram in Live Edit mode. Users are able to move a task, move start and end, set and remove connectors. Modified data is submitted to a database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROl4n.png)

Now we need to disable editing single tasks completely and certain handles of the task's bar depending on the task's attributes, e.g. the start date must not be editable, but the end date can still be moved, duration as well.

The library offers enabling/disabling elements of the chart down to the level of all elements, but not for single elements, as far as I can see. Is this possible at all?

We tried to enable/disable editing of single tasks by attribute edit in the data structure without any effect:

```
{
    id: 26235,
    name: "AP 10",
    parent: 7251,
    typ: "AD",
    status: 5,
    actualStart: Date.UTC(2024, 3-1, 14),
    actualEnd: Date.UTC(2024, 3-1, 21),
    baselineStart: Date.UTC(2024, 3-1, 11),
    baselineEnd: Date.UTC(2024, 3-1, 18),
    edit: false,
    connector: [
        {
            connectTo: 26236,
            connectorType: 'finish-start'
        }
    ]
}
```

Disabling certain handles of a bar may be impossible completely, I have found nothing about it in the documentation.